# url rewrite/redirect on iis7 redirect to mobile site

Tags: redirect, iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I have made all of my mobile folder/pages  structure like the desktop version.
I need to make sure all the requests from mobile devices will be re-directed to a mobile domain.
what I would like to do is if a URL is opened from a mobile device like this: http://www.example.com/test/test.asp  will be redirected to http://m.example.com/test/test.asp

this question might be asked before but I need to make sure it works.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solve it.

```
<rule name="Mobile Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobil|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobil|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobil|phone" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.yoursite.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1169853.aspx

This amends your web config to redirect -- not sure if it can be used on the page level, but it might be a good start.

Comment: thanks for your response, ive already tried this but like you mentioned it wont use it for the page level.

Comment: What do you call on page level?

Comment: basically, any HTTP request and redirect to a mobile version if link opened from a mobile device if www.example.com/about.asp it will go to m.example.com/about.asp